# Where can I find IntelliTrace Standalone Collector 2017 installation

Tags: visual-studio

Where can I find IntelliTrace Standalone Collector 2017.
I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 and need Standalone Collector for IntelliTrace, I cant find it with google or on my.visualstudio.com page.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01d5bf01-852c-4798-a196-476efb996e49/vs2017-intellitrace-standalone-collector-download?forum=vsdebug appears to have a solution. If this solves your problem you can consider answering your own question with this answer

Comment: there is only 2013 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found installation file in my Visual Studio installation as per microsoft doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-intellitrace-stand-alone-collector?view=vs-2017

Visual Studio installation folder:

Copy IntelliTraceCollection.cab from the folder where the collector is installed, for example:

..\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace

or, for previous versions of Visual Studio:

..\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\12.0.0